# Get the name of a Thunderbird attachment

Tags: javascript, mozilla, email-attachments, add-on, thunderbird-addon

Is there a way to get the filename and/or filepath of an attachments from the current TB message?
I tried this ([HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MozMmsMessage.attachments#MmsAttachment) is the link):

```
function AttachmentNames() {  
    var attachments = instanceOfMozMmsMessage.attachments;
}
```

with different alerts like `attachments.length`,`attachments[0].filepath` etc., but nothing happened (i guess it's improper for current mails anyway).

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.xulforum.org/mozcamp2012/dzslides/template.html#34.2 along with the demo addon, or http://jonathan.xulforum.org/files/glodebug.xpi

There's also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Thunderbird/Demo_Addon